# Model rotating on Z-axis is off

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an object on it's own axis by means of Matrices, but I've ran into a problem. Rotating on either X or Y axis produces the expected results, but when it comes to rotating on the Z-axis, the entire model appears to pivot around the Z-axis as if there was an invisible pole under it, where when rotating from the X or Y axis, the invisible pole runs through the model.

```
glm::mat4 rotateMatrix(GLfloat angle, glm::vec3 axis)
{
    axis = glm::normalize(axis);
    GLfloat s = sin(angle);
    GLfloat c = cos(angle);
    GLfloat oc = 1.0f - c;

    return glm::mat4(
        oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,          oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s, oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s, 0.0,
        oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s, oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,          oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s, 0.0,
        oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s, oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s, oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,          0.0,
        0.0,                               0.0,                               0.0,                               1.0
        );
}
```

**Within draw function:**

```
_prog.setUniform("Translation", glm::vec3(0.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f));
_prog.setUniform("Rotate", rotateMatrix(45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
_model.render();
```

Comment: The rotation matrix looks correct. But what is the purpose of the "Translation"? What happens if you remove that line of the draw function?

Comment: @DavidK "Translation" is a vec3 in GLSL used to move/position the model in the world. I'm using it much like glTranslatef(float, float, float).

Comment: It seemed it would do something of the sort. I just haven't seen that particular notation anywhere else. But it seems you are translating before rotating, which is apt to cause problems (as noted in the answer by @Sunius). That's why I ask what happens if you don't translate at all.

Comment: Another question: where is your model relative to the coordinate axes _before_ you perform these operations on it? That is, what were the original ranges of min/max x coordinates, min/max y coordinates, min/max z coordinates, before the translation?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you rotated a translated model. Check that your transform order is correct:

1. Scale model;
2. Rotate model;
3. Translate model;

Also, make sure that model itself at the origin of the coordinate system.

Comment: That very much depends on how the matrix library is implemented. If it matches OpenGL (which glm does), then it is column-major and uses post-multiplication. The order you call those individual operations in such a situation is reversed.

Comment: Technically, the "order of operations" is the same. The tricky part is, if you compose operations together by multiplying matrices, to remember whether the "first" operation is defined by the rightmost or leftmost matrix. In this example the operations are not composed by matrix multiplication, so I think that particular concern doesn't apply.